# How did Mary Poppins' bag work, how did she fly?

Tags: mary-poppins

In a recent bout of speculation I had the thought that Mary Poppins might be a Timelord, considering that her bag (and umbrella?) seem decidedly TARDIS like (bigger on the inside, can fly, etc).
Assuming she isn't actually a Timelord (but if you have evidence she is please add it), is there any explanation for how Mary Poppins' bag worked and how she was able to fly?

My speculations are based off 20+ year old memories of the Disney movie.

Comment: Which canon? Original book series? Original Disney movie? Soviet Movie? [Other adaptations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Poppins#Adaptations)?

Comment: @DVK I added to the question.

Comment: Wow! Who knew there were so many Mary Poppins!!

Comment: Being a Disney movie, it works by Mickey Magic :)

Comment: I think these are two different questions, her umbrella flew her.

Comment: @Kevin I tend to agree, but when I think about it I can't remember a time when she was flying without the bag.  Is it possible that the bag did the flying, and the umbrella was just for stability?

Comment: Also if you're assuming she isn't a timelord, why is it tagged as such?

Comment: @Pureferret dunno. I didn't add that tag.

Comment: I'm convinced that "a spoonful of sugar" is a euphamism for some sort of illicit substance.  Possibly PCP... They did jump out a window right?

Comment: It seemed suspicious to me that her powers were consistent with that of a freed elemental spirit in the game Shadowrun, which struct me as an entertaining adventure seed...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The in-universe explanation is "magic - don't ask". Howver, there is some speculation we can do. The umbrella, at least in the film, merely focussed the wind, and enabled her to take advantage of it to move herself about. She had to be taken to "somewhere else", because she was definitively "other".

The bag must have been a portal to a tract of space, not infinite, but large enough for all of her possessions - including a standard lamp. In the film, she does have to explore a long way down in the bag, but it clearly does have a base to it.

The other bag explanation is that it is simply a womans handbag, which, as we all know, can contain twice as much as it appears to on the outside. The maths of this are still obscure.

Comment: +1 "The other bag explanation is that it is simply a womans handbag, which, as we all know, can contain twice as much as it appears to on the outside. The maths of this are still obscure." ROFLOL

Answer (score 5):

In the movie the answer is basically "magic".  We don't have it explained to us.  I like to think of the bag as a [Bag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_holding) of [Holding](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BagOfHolding).  I have no idea about the umbrella.